# DL360 - Windows Server 2012 Core hyper-v on SD card?

Tags: hyper-v, hp-proliant, hyper-v-server-2012

My "plan" is to install 2012 Server Core with the Hyper-v role on an internal SD card in a DL360 G7 (Bios P68 05/05/2011), and put the guest VHDs on iSCSI storage.

Two questions:

1. Is this viable? Or am I mad?
2. When I try and install my OS (either via SmartStart or directly), the SD card storage is not recognised (SmartStart says "No disk available for installing an operating system"). I've tried a variety of SD cards - admittedly all from SanDisk. Do I need to load specific drivers for Server2012? Am I missing something fundamental?

Answer (score 3):

1. Sorta. You can install Hyper-V Server 2012 on the SD. You can not install Server 2012 with Hyper-V to a SD however. Those are two different products with unfortunately similar names.

   Hyper-V Server 2008 R2 (2.0) can be booted from a SD card too.
2. There are special directions for doing this, you can't just run setup as you're trying.

   Microsoft has provided directions [Deploying Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2008 R2 on USB Flash Drive](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee731893%28WS.10%29.aspx), which work for both 2008 R2 and 2012.

Side note: The SD card must appear as a USB disk device, this is dependent on the SD controller. In HP and Dell servers I've seen, this is the case. I've only seen otherwise in embedded hardware.

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, booting from an SD card is not supported for Hyper-V. This makes the rest of the discussion mostly irrelevant as you simply shouldn't be doing this in production.

Comment: So it's fair to say that Chris S's "Deploying Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2008 R2 on USB Flash Drive" link really just applies test environments, yes? And from what I can see it also involves booting off a VHD?

Comment: @Pete It depends if you have an SD controller that shows as a permanent USB device, and if you want Hyper-V or Server 2012 **with** Hyper-V

Comment: I'm pretty sure my hardware supports it - but I guess I need to check licensing. I have Server2012 Standard licenses - and as far as I can see they each support 1 host and 2 guest instances. Need to check the position if the host is Hyper-v server?

Answer (score 1):

The SmartStart disk will not allow you to install on the SD card.

VMware vSphere 5 addresses this by telling you NOT to use the SmartStart disk.  I run VMware vSphere 5 on an SD card in an HP DL 360 and am anticipating using HyperV next.  HP had a specific version to install.  It may have that for HyperV also.  I should check but I'm busy at TechStraviganza in the NYC Microsoft offices right now.